# Are there benefits to using Greenify with Android Nougat?

Tags: battery-life, 7.0-nougat, privacy, disable-app, greenify

[Greenify by Oasis Feng](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) ([donation package](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify.pro)) is a well-regarded tool to manually and automatically freeze apps that are not in use.  Typically, Greenify's benefits are to:

- increase battery duration
- improve task-switching
- reduce data usage
- increase privacy (by not having apps performing background operations, including data transfer).

Android Nougat (7.x) has many new battery saving features as well as improved memory management.

Are there benefits to using Greenify with Android Nougat on non-rooted devices?

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience and opinion, no. I have tried using it for about a 3 weeks, and haven't seen any improvement. Maybe it works for rooted or custom Rom devices, but generally Nougat does a pretty good job.

Comment: This.  I gave it go as well, but noticed little change.  And that change was probably just placebo effect.  Maybe on rooted devices it is more powerful, but for non-rooted its just another do-nothing so-called battery saver.